# Bootstrap 3 popover wrong position when used on span two lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to display more information about certain parts of a paragraph in an html page using Bootstrap's popover.

In order to achieve that I'm using a span with a popover appearing on hover:

```
<p class="container">
    Lorem ipsum <span class="pop" data-content="Popover">dolor sit amet</span>laborum.
</p>
```

And then calling the popover function on all required elements.

```
$('.pop').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        animation: true,
        title: '',
        content: 'This is the popover content.',
        delay: {'show' : 0, 'hide' : 300}
});
```

This is working fine as long as the span that will create the popover is within the same line, i.e. the popover is centered properly. If, however, the span *spans* two lines, the popover doesn't appear above the span. I'm looking for a way to fix this behavior as intended, i.e. always have the popover on top of the span, even if it spans two lines.

You can see a fiddle of this behavior here (hover on highlighted text):  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLQQL/157/)

Answer (score 0):

It just missing css only. Here is your updated fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pop').each(function() {
    var $elem = $(this);
    $elem.popover({
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'hover',
      html: true,
      container: $elem,
      animation: true,
      title: '',
      content: 'This is the popover content. You should be able to mouse over HERE.',
      delay: {
        'show': 0,
        'hide': 300
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 200px 50px;
}
span.pop {
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  background-color: rgba(50, 230, 50, 0.5);
}
span.pop.wrong {
  background-color: rgba(230, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
.container {
  width: 750px;
}
span.pop.wrong {
  background-color: rgba(230, 50, 50, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="container">
  Lorem ipsum <span class="pop" data-content="This popover is fine">dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea <span class="pop wrong" data-content="This popover is in the wrong position">commodo consequat</span>. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

only add css

```
span.pop.wrong {display: inline-block}
```